# how to reduce line spacing in huxtable/huxreg

Tags: r-markdown, huxtable

I am working with huxreg/huxtable in RMarkdown documents. As I have a very long regression table, so I need to reduce font size / line spacing to fit it into one page. I can control font_size, however, I do not find a possibility to reduce line spacing, regardless of what options I use, e.g.

```r
huxreg(regression_model,
  error_pos = "right") %>% 
  set_font_size(6) %>% 
  set_tb_padding(0)
```

The [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/huxtable/vignettes/huxtable.html) suggests ways to fiddle with "spacing", yet, there seems to be no clear option.

Does someone has a clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this article will be of use:

https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/reference/padding.html

> "These functions set the space around the edges of cells, within the borders."

```
left_padding(ht)
left_padding(ht) <- value
set_left_padding(ht, row, col, value )
map_left_padding(ht, row, col, fn)

right_padding(ht)
right_padding(ht) <- value
set_right_padding(ht, row, col, value )
map_right_padding(ht, row, col, fn)

top_padding(ht)
top_padding(ht) <- value
set_top_padding(ht, row, col, value )
map_top_padding(ht, row, col, fn)

bottom_padding(ht)
bottom_padding(ht) <- value
set_bottom_padding(ht, row, col, value )
map_bottom_padding(ht, row, col, fn)
```

Comment: Thanks! I get rid of some space with set_bottom_padding(0) + set_top_padding(0) but it's not single spaced.